# Prove that $g\in S$ is a fixed point of $K$ if and only if $g$ satisfies the D.E. $g'(x)=F(x,g(x))$ with I.C. $g(a)=0$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I'm reading Intro to Topology by Mendelson.

The entire problem statement is,

Let $F\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued function defined and continuous on the plane. For each continuous function $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ we may define a new continuous function $Kf\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ by setting $$Kf(t)=\int_a^t F(x,f(x))dx$$ where $t\in[a,b]$. Thus, if $S$ is the set of continuous real-valued functions defined on $[a,b]$, $K$ defines a transformation of $S$ onto itself.

Prove that $g\in S$ is a fixed point of $K$ if and only if $g$ satisfies the differential equation $g'(x)=F(x,g(x))$ with initial condition $g(a)=0$.

My attempt at the proof is,

$(\Longleftarrow)$ Suppose $g$ satisfies the differential equation $g'(x)=F(x,g(x))$ with initial condition $g(a)=0$. If we integrate both sides from $a$ to $t$ we get, $$\int_a^t g'(x)dx=\int_a^t F(x,g(x))dx$$
$$g(t)-g(a)=\int_a^t F(x,g(x))=Kg(t).$$
Using the initial condition $g(a)=0$ gives
$$g(t)=Kg(t)$$ for $t\in[a,b]$. Thus $g$ is a fixed point of $K$.

$(\Longrightarrow)$ Suppose that $g$ is a fixed point of $K$. That is,$$Kg(t)=\int_a^t F(x,g(x))dx=g(t).$$ Then we have, $$g'(t)=F(t,g(t))-F(a,g(a))$$
(The following is where I feel I might be doing something wrong.)
Since $g(a)=0$, $g'(a)=F(a,g(a))=0$ and so we get $$g'(t)=F(t,g(t))$$ with initial condition $g(a)=0$.

Thanks for any hints or feedback!

Comment: I assume you meant $Kf(t) = \int_a^tF(x,f(x))dx$ in your first equation?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Let me go ahead and edit that. Thank you!

Comment: the equation $g'(t)=F(t,g(t))-F(a,g(a))$ is wrong, it is $g'(t)=F(t,g(t))$.

Comment: I see. So that actually clears things up. Since I can show the initial condition with the fixed point property. Thanks for the help!

Comment: BTW, love the picture of Jimi in you user profile.  And muchas gracias for being so "accepting"!

Comment: Haha, thanks. Jimi is awesome. And you're welcome, your answer helped clear things up in addition to Juan's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, taking

$g(t) = Kg(t) = \int_a^tF(x, g(x))$

implies (and I'm not going to try and prove this derivative exists here, rather simply stipulate as to that)

$g'(t) = F(t, g(t))$

directly, *not*

$g'(t) = F(t, g(t)) - F(a, g(a))$,

by a standard application of the usual Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  The fact that $g(a) = 0$ is already there for you, insofar as

$g(a) = \int_a^aF(x, g(x))dx = 0$,

since the "closed interval" $[a, a]$ has measure $0$ in any event.

Hope this clarifies.  Tally-ho!!!

Comment: Yes that did. Thanks for the feedback!